# Storyboard Segue not loading view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uistoryboard

I'm trying to segue in code. the prepareForSegue function runs and shows correct destination view controller, but nothing happens. Any idéas on what I'm missing or what I have misconfigured?

**View controller possible path:**

```
A ->B (sgueResultat)
or
A->C (sgueStopSplash)
```

**Code that chooses the segue:**

```
if (proversion)
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sgueResultat" sender:self];

}
else {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sgueStopSplash" sender:self];

}
```

`

**The prepareForSegue that I can confirm is running by NSLog:**

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 NSLog(@"Source Controller = %@", [segue sourceViewController]);
 NSLog(@"Destination Controller = %@", [segue destinationViewController]);
 NSLog(@"Segue Identifier = %@", [segue identifier]);
```

**Nslog output:**

```
2012-06-26 22:22:26.002 ClosetV2[2333:fb03] Source Controller = <ABStartViewController: 0xeb12270>
2012-06-26 22:22:26.002 ClosetV2[2333:fb03] Destination Controller = <SplashAfterStopViewController: 0x6b2c9e0>
2012-06-26 22:22:26.003 ClosetV2[2333:fb03] Segue Identifier = sgueStopSplash
2012-06-26 22:22:26.003 ClosetV2[2333:fb03] sgueStopSplash
```

Regards
Andreas

Comment: What is the segue configured to do? If it is configured to "push" is the source view controller embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: Both Segues are set as Modal.

Comment: Are the segues configured in any other way? Also, what is the forth log output line? It is not included in the code snippet from `prepareForSegue:sender:` that you included.

Comment: What happens if you put log statements inside the `initWithCoder:`, `awakeFromNib`, `viewDidLoad:`, or `viewWillAppear:` methods of `SplashAfterStopViewController`?

Comment: David: Fourth log line is in prepareForSegue:                                             if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"sgueStopSplash"])
        {
            NSLog(@"sgueStopSplash");

Comment: Philip: When adding Nslog statements to functions described, none of them hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your segues are set to "modal" in your storyboard (or custom if you are fancy).

I remember when I first started using segues when storyboarding came out, I kept trying to use push, which you can only do if you have an embedded UINavigationController.  Otherwise, a push segue will simply not function.

Another thought... where is the code below executing?  If an animation is already taking place or if the current view is not already showing on the screen, it will not function properly.  For example, if you have this code in your viewDidLoad, it will not work.

```
if (proversion)
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sgueResultat" sender:self];

}
else {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sgueStopSplash" sender:self];

}
```

Edit: Updated Answer

Waiting for the [self dismissModalViewController:YES] animation to complete before performing your segue is actually annoying and somewhat messy.  I don't think there is a "proper" way to do it.  However, if you put the following method inside the view that has the modal controller and send it a message after using [self dismissModalViewController:YES], you should be in good shape.

```
- (void)waitUntilModalControllerIsDismissed
{
    if(self.modalViewController)
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(waitUntilModalControllerIsDismissed:)
                   withObject:nil 
                   afterDelay:0.1f];
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        //At this point, the modal animation will be completed and you can perform your segue if you want
    }  

}
```

Comment: It probably happens from some action like a button tap, a gesture or a device shake. That would be more reasonable. (Still only guessing though)

Comment: An animation could be taking place, as I had a [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];, Confirmed! Changing to NO solved the problem. Any way to wait for animation to complete?

Comment: Updated my answer to include how to wait for the modal animation before performing the segue.